# VRP with score dependens on more than one job in optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner, vehicle-routing

We are trying to solve a VRP with Optaplanner.
The score calculation runs via constraint streams.

Now I have two vehicles (A and B) and want to schedule two jobs (J1 and J2).
The construction heuristic (FIRST_FIT_DECREASING) schedules J1 to A and J2 to B, what is correct so far.

Now the two jobs also have an attribute "customer", and I want to assign a penalty if the customer of the two jobs is the same but the vehicles are different.

For this purpose, I have created a constraint in the ConstraintProvider that filters all jobs via groupBy that have the same customer but different vehicles.

If I now switch on the FULL_ASSERT_MODE, an IllegalStateException occurs after scheduling J2, because the score that is calculated incrementally is different from the score for the complete calculation.
I suspect this is because the VariableListener, which recalculates the times of the jobs, only tells the ScoreDirector about a change to Job J2 for my shadowvariables and therefore only changes the score part that is related to it.

How can I tell Optaplanner that the score for J1 must also be recalculated? I can't get to job J1 via the VariableListener to tell the ScoreDirector that the score has to be changed here.

Or does this problem require a different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem that is a bit hard to explain fully. TLDR version: constraint streams only react to changes to objects which are coming from either `from()`, `join()` or `ifExists()`. Changes on objects not coming through these statements will not be caught, and therefore causing score corruptions. Longer explanation follows.

Consider a hypothetical Constraint Stream like this:

```
constraintFactory.from(Shift.class)
    .join(Shift.class)
    .filter((shift1, shift2) -> shift1.getEmployee() == shift2.getEmployee())
    ...
```

This constraint stream will work just fine, because if you change `Shift` by setting a different employee, the `Shift`s will be re-evaluated. They enter the stream via `from()` and `join()`, which is how CS knows to re-evaluate `Shifts` when they change.

Now consider this constraint stream instead:

```
constraintFactory.from(Shift.class)
    .filter(shift -> shift.getEmployee().getName() == "Lukas")
    ...
```

This constraint stream will be re-evaluated, if `Shift` changes. But when the `name` of `Employee` changes, the constraint stream will not be re-evaluated; `Employee` is neither in `from()` nor in `join()`, changes to `Employee` will not trigger re-evaluation of the constraint stream.

In your particular situation, you need to ensure several things:

- Variable listeners mark everything as changed that actually changes.
- If you modify problem facts, you need to make sure your variable listeners handle that too.
- Objects that you want your constraint stream to react to are coming in through `from()` or a `join()`.